# How to set correctly dynamically defined LinearLayout with landscape/portrait rotation?

Tags: android, android-layout

I defined dynamically all GUI components.When the  Cntrl+F11 is first pressed the layout updates correctly to from portrait to landscape. But when I press Cntrl+F11 again, layout remains in its "landscape" look. How can I update it for "portrait" look again? The source code:

```
//Main Layout ll
LinearLayout ll ;
ll.setOrientation (LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

//Inner layout ll2 is inside of the main layout ll
LinearLayout ll2 = new LinearLayout (this);
ll2.setWeight(1.0f);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
lp.weight = 0.25f;

//Button b is inside of the inner layout ll2
Button b = new Button (this);
b.setLayoutParams(lp);
ll2.addView (b);

ll.addView(ll2);
```

I tried this solution (from this site):
I added function

```
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      setContentView(ll);
    }
```

and set I in AndroidManifest

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

but it stiil doesn't work.Thanks.

Comment: ADDITIONAL COMMENT: According to NagarjunaReddy answer, I wrote d.getOrintation() in onResume() function. I see that it changes to landscape orientation with first press Cntrl+f11, but with next presses of  Cntrl+f11 it stays same (remains with value "1" = "landscape"). Any ideas why it does happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this in xml file

android:orientatoin="portrait "

it is also possible to write in onCreate() method also

You Also specify in ANDROID_MANIFEST like this

```
 <activity android:name=".activityName" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

Comment: Hi NagarjunaReddy, thanks. It looks like a good solution. But now I tried it, and it didn't work. When I press Cntrl+F11 second time, the emulator still has landscape orientation.

Comment: WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
  Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
  if (d.getWidth() > d.getHeight()){
   //---landscape mode---
     Log.d(“Orientation”, “Landscape mode”);
     }
  else
   {
   //---portrait mode---
  Log.d(“Orientation”, “Portrait mode”);
  }

Comment: setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: Hi NagarjunaReddy.Thanks again. It is very helpful

Comment: To NagarjunaReddy. Although I still didn't solve it completely. When I insert the code that you wrote into onConfigurationChanged() function, I don't see any logs and it looks like this function isn't called at all. When I insert this code into onCreate(), I see logs , but only "LandscapeOrientetion" logs. It looks like the "Portrait" orientation isn't recognized by emulator. I also tried now to write setRequestedOrientation() function , but it gives always portrait orientation. Thank you very much, it gives me a direction to think.

Comment: Hi, finally it worked. Thank you for the idea that helped me to understand and to test it.

Answer (score 0):

To revert configuration back to Portrait use key-combinations ctrl+F9

Comment: Hi Jitendra Sharma, thanks. The ctrl+F9 doesn't work on my emulator, it looks like nothing happens when I press it.